# Duvida de como criar um layout para edição de informações

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

estou desenvolvendo uma ferramenta interna para controle de despesas de viagem dos colaboradores, porem estou com uma grande duvida.

vou explicar os passos que segui ate o momento.

--> primeiramente a pessoa entra no portal e solicita uma viagem com data de ida, data de volta, destino e mais algumas informações.

--> o superior desta pessoa recebe um e-mail de notificação que a mesma esta solicitando uma viagem, ele pode autorizar ou negar a viagem.

--> supondo que o superior autorizou a viagem, o colaborador receberá um novo e-mail notificando que a viagem dele foi autorizada.

--> neste momento o colaborador já fez a viagem e vem prestar contas da viagem que ele fez.

**minha duvida esta aqui**

--> a viagem é dividida por dias, dia de ida ate o dia de volta 
EX: 01/01/2018 até 03/01/2018, sendo que tenho que preencher as informações da viagem assim conforme a imagem em anexo
[image: imagem planilha]

Qual a melhor forma que trabalhar com este layout no html? Alguém conhece alguma ferramenta ou possa me dar uma ideia de como prosseguir. Obrigado a todos.

Esta é uma imagem da planilha que o pessoal usa hoje

Comment: Não seria melhor fazer um Formulário do que uma Tabela?

Comment: Você pode fazer isso dentro de um form, usando Labels e Inputs... e para ficar com aparencia de tabela, pode usar o sistema de colunas do bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Sobre layout vc pode usar tabelas com labels e inputs normalmente, ex:

```
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Horário de entrada</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="entrada">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Horário de saída</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="saida">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Vai ficar com cara de excell, que acho que é o que vc quer

Answer (score 0):

Olha pessoal obrigado pela ajuda te todos, resolvi o problema com um formulario basico porem utilizei um lib chamada angular-steps onde ele trabalha com "abas"

segue foto de como ficou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]